# Javascript: slideDown on first click, open link on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and javascript and have a problem I could not resolve: 
I have a hamburger menu on a mobile website with submenus. When opening the menu only the "mobilemenufirstorder" class should be displayed.

This is easily possible by just changing this line of code:

```
#mobilemenusecondorder {
    display: block;
}
```

When clicking a first order link that has items in the "mobilemenusecondorder" div, they should be displayed and the link should not be followed.
Preferably but not necessarily the "mobilemenusecondorder" div should slide in.
When clicking the "mobilemenufirstorder" link again, the link should be opened. 
When clicking a link that doesn't have links inside the mobilemenusecondorder class, the link should be opened right away.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Here is a link to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheBB23/dfnewt4y/3/

Comment: Instead of an `<a>` element, you could do a span that has an onClick handler for the ones that aren't links.

Comment: I could create a span around the <a> elements. But I could either create them around every a link or no links because the website is based on a web tool. I only have limited access to. 
Would it still work and if yes, how?